# How can I run commands on existing cmd window from another cmd window?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, wmic

I have one command prompt instance running (lets call it A). A takes 10 mins time to load (Loading includes intialisation, running few pre requisite commands etc). 
I have one more command prompt instance running (lets call it B). B is just simple command prompt.

Now I want to run a command on A instance from B instance. 
Something like, 
e.g.

```
cmd B:> call A.exe "dosomething"
```

Now here I want "dosomething" to be ran on A cmd instance.

**I tried with wmic**.

```
C:\Users\dbe1>wmic process where 'caption like "%cmd.exe"' get  name, processid
Name     ProcessId
cmd.exe  2628
cmd.exe  17620
```

I got process IDs.Now I can call to treminate, create etc on this process IDs.

```
wmic process where processid="18172" call terminate
```

It works just fine, since **terminate** method is understood by windows.I want to call "**dosomething**" here which is my custom requirement.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Win32_Process Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg196675(v=vs.85).aspx).

The `Win32_Process` class exposes the following methods:

- `AttachDebugger` method: launches the currently registered debugger for the process;
- `Create` method: creates a new process;
- `GetAvailableVirtualSize` method: retrieves the currently size in bytes of the free virtual address space available to the process;
- `GetOwner` method: retrieves the user name and domain name under which the process is running;
- `GetOwnerSid` method: retrieves the security identifier (SID) for the owner of the process;
- `SetPriority` method: attempts to change the execution priority of the process;
- `Terminate` method: terminates the process and all of its threads.

Comment: I don't want to call default methods like Terminate,Create etc. which are provided by windows.
I want to run another batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have something running in A capable of being told what to do, but you can do it: in a cmd script, A.cmd, running in cmd.exe A, add the following:

```
waitfor dosomething
```

then in cmd.exe B, type the following:

```
waitfor /SI dosomething
```

A.cmd (and any other instances or running cmd scripts executing `waitfor dosomething` at that time) will execute the next line of script: this could either be something hard-coded into A.cmd, or you could do something like the following:

**B.cmd:**

```
echo @echo Hello World > dosomething.cmd
waitfor /SI dosomething
```

**A.cmd:**

```
waitfor dosomething
if EXIST dosomething.cmd call dosomething.cmd
```

One drawback to this is that each individual cmd.exe is not multi-threaded, but you can just overcome that by running multiple instances (i.e., multi-process instead of multi-thread); you'd also have to put each instance into its own folder so it would have its own copy of dosomething.cmd to manipulate.

**B.cmd:**

```
echo @echo Hello A instance 1 > \A1\dosomething.cmd
echo @echo Hello A instance 2 > \A2\dosomething.cmd

REM both instances will be signaled by the following line
waitfor /SI dosomething
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @John.
I got the idea. I have tried it and working seamlessly except a little glitch.

Now, I am sending **dosomething ** signal from A.cmd to B.cmd. I am getting "Signal received" message at the B.cmd. 

If B.cmd is waiting for more than 1 signal,Is there any way by which I can run particular script on B.cmd (target), depending on the name of signal it is receiving?

Comment: Not multi-threaded ... My original answer addresses this: run multiple instances of b.cmd, each with their own action script to perform